# Is Mongo storing dates as UTC?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am storing dates in Mongo DB using Mongoose, they should be in UTC, but I am seeing this using a Mongo IDE (Studio3T) - I take it that the `+0000` does not mean UTC?

```
"eventDate" : ISODate("2019-12-27T17:01:00.000+0000"),
```

Comment: UTC is always +00:00, so where’s the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+0000` means UTC according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators). The letter `Z` is also possible to indicate UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,Dude! By default the dates are stored in UTC format in MongoDB.
For further information,head over to below links.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/

[MongoDb BSON stores Date in UTC time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654567/mongodb-bson-stores-date-in-utc-time)